# Check CUDA GPU usage

Tags: nvidia, cuda, boinc

I've been number crunching using boinc for several years now and I'm starting to get into more computational stuff that uses CUDA.  I was wondering if there is a way to check which processes are making use of CUDA at any given point.  I'm using an nvidia GeForce 8400 GS if it helps.

I've poked around a bit on the web and the best recommendation I got was to use `nvidia-smi`.  However, upon some more poking around, I found that `nvidia-smi` only gives an output for some graphics cards (my GEFORCE is not among them).  Hence the following output:

```
    +------------------------------------------------------+                       
    | NVIDIA-SMI 5.319.32   Driver Version: 319.32         |                       
    |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
    | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
    | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
    |===============================+======================+======================|
    |   0  GeForce 8400GS      Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
    | 30%   74C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |      282MB /   511MB |     N/A      Default |
    +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
    |  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
    |=============================================================================|
    |    0            Not Supported                                               |
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.